# technical clothing and fabric softener

Tags: clothing, gear-care

I just found out that my technical apparel<sup>1</sup> has been washed with 2 in 1 washing powder. I have been very careful about washing my clothes and told everyone about it. I did not know that a couple of weeks ago the 2 in 1 powder was bought because it was on offer, it was only when I went to put a wash on today that I found out. So my question is what damage would have occurred to my clothing in about 3 washes and is there anything I can do about it?

<sub>1. Softshell waterproof/windproof jacket and sports compression fit baselayer</sub>

Comment: What type of clothing? Jackets, insulating layers, pants? What materials/types? Gore-Tex, membranes, wool?

Comment: Softshell waterproof/windproof jacket and sports compression fit baselayer

Answer (score 5):

I give this with the heavy qualification that it depends on the exact brands of clothes and products involved.

Your waterproof jacket is *probably* fine if it is **water-proof** and not **water-resistant**.  The waterproof fabrics out there tend to not be as sensitive to detergents.  However, if it is water-resistant, you will probably need to refresh it.  [Nikwax](http://www.rei.com/product/724690/nikwax-tx-direct-20-wash-in-water-repellent-treatment-10-oz) makes some wash in products for this purpose.

If your baselayer is a wicking fabric, you shouldn't make a habit of this. I contacted UnderArmour through their site to ask about this.  According to their tech (live online chat), if you only washed it once you are probably okay but make sure you stick to the directions in the future.